# Adding an <a> tag to flexbox messes eveything up

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to add links for every box but whenever I try to add an "a" tag it messes everything up. What am I missing :-/ ?

```css
.services-area {
  padding: 120px 0;
}

.container3 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: #fff;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main-text2 {
  color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: 0 10%;
}

.main-text2 h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.services {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.service {
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 45px 55px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.service:hover {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px;
  border-color: #fff;
  border: 1px;
}

.link {
  display: grid;
}

.service-image {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 0 23px;
}

.service-title {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  align-items: end;
}

.service-text {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}

.service-price {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.price-underline {
  text-decoration: underline #999997 2px;
}
```

```html
<section class="services-area">
  <div class="container3">
    <div class="main-text2">
      <h2>
        We have a vast offer that covers all renovation needs
      </h2>
      <div class="services">
        <div class="service">
          <a href="sevice.html" target="_blank" class="link">
            <div> <img class="service-image " src="images/paint-roller (1).png" alt=""></div>
            <p class="service-title">Construction</p>
            <p class="service-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, seagna aliqua maecenas accum lacus vel facilisis.</p>
            <p class="service-price"> Prices from <span class="price-underline">$30/m2</span></p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
          <a href="sevice.html" target="_blank">
            <div> <img class="service-image " src="images/painting.png" alt=""></div>
            <p class="service-title"> Electrics</p>
            <p class="service-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, seagna aliqua maecenas accum lacus vel facilisis.</p>
            <p class="service-price">Prices from <span class="price-underline">$25/point</span></p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
          <a href="sevice.html" target="_blank">
            <div> <img class="service-image " src="images/paint-roller.png" alt=""></div>
            <p class="service-title"> Plumbing</p>
            <p class="service-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, seagna aliqua maecenas accum lacus vel facilisis.</p>
            <p class="service-price">Prices from<span class="price-underline"> $35/point</span></p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `display: flex` affects the way the element's _direct descendants_ are laid out. By wrapping the content in an `<a>` you've changed the descendants to a single element, the `<a>`. You could move the flex rules to the `<a>` or as [johannes suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76066202/636077) you could set `display: contents` to have it act as if there was no intermediate element.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS rule, so the `a` tags which are direct children of the `.services` flex container will be ignored concerning the flexbox model (i.e. they will not be treated as flex items, but "pass" that role to their child elements)

```
.services > a {
   display: contents;
}
```